# What size fuse wire do I need for a 4 kW single phase 220V geyser?

Tags: electrical, wiring

What is the type and gauge of wire that I should use for fuse wire which is feeding a 4 kW single-phase geyser?

Comment: 4 kilowatt on 220V needs 20amps

Comment: What is a geyser in this sense?

Comment: Probably an electric shower or some other type of tankless water heater.